# This host was not in contact with the Host Monitor

Tags: hadoop

I added a new host successfully without any roles though using cloudera manager.

But it keeps giving:

Bad : This host was in contact with the Cloudera Manager Server. This host was not in contact with the Host Monitor.

Why is that? How do I fix it? My host monitor service is running just fine. It is receiving hearbeats as well. Not sure why it is not in contact with host mintor? Please help

Comment: Check `clouder-scm-agent service` state

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaReddy: It's running on both the nodes

Comment: hey @gags, where you able to solve this issue? Facing the same problem here with one of my nodes. Thanks